# How to split JSON columns in Power BI

Tags: json, parsing, powerbi, powerquery, m

[image][image]

I have imported JSON data from Hive database. The structure looks like the attached. JSON data has been dumped to Hive without normalizing. Is it possible to parse the data?. For example, in the attached image, the `mentionedlocations` column has some places mentioned and I want them to be in separate rows.

Comment: Edit your post with the specified pictures ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Json.Document` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/json-document) to read the column as JSON.

I'd suggest creating a custom column with this formula:

```
Record.ToTable(Json.Document([mentionedlocations]))
```

and then expanding that column to get the multiple rows you want.

---

Putting these together:

```
= Table.ExpandTableColumn(
      Table.AddColumn(PreviousStep, "Custom",
          each Record.ToTable(Json.Document([mentionedlocations]))),
      "Custom", {"Name"}, {"locations"})
```

This takes the `PreviousStep` in the query, adds a `Custom` column which converts the JSON text into a table and then expands the `Name` column in each of the tables in the `Custom` column and renames the column `locations`.

Comment: using the Json.document throws an error like.  i have tried using the custom column formula which gives the following error.                                                #Failed to resolve name 'Json.Document'. It is not a valid table, variable, or function name#

Comment: It's an M language function, not a DAX function. You have to use it in the query editor.

Comment: Noted and can able to get the result now,

Answer (score 1):

More easy peasy:

1. Right click on the column > Transform > JSON

[image]

2. Now use the button at the top right of the same column and Power BI is going to use the JSON element as the column name

[image]