# How to split json columns in tableau?

Tags: json, powerbi, tableau-api

I am trying to split json columns using tableau. I have found a solution in Power BI, NOw i am trying to repeat the same in tableau. Please find below the link for Power BI solution. The M-code worked perfectly in Power BI that gave me a table. Now In tableau Is there any means to do it. I know about split option in tableau and also custom split,But after split each value is separated as column wise, while the desired output is row wise.

[Json column split in power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577136/how-to-split-json-columns-in-power-bi)

Answer (score 0):

try for substring({your field},1,1)

Comment: You can add comment for such a tip

Comment: Thanks for the tip. but i need something more than a substring.

Comment: Post examples? Then the desired output